# How to import string to app.yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, environment-variables

I am running GAE application with python 2.7 + Flask and also using SENDGRID third party library to send email.

And also, I want to upload this project to Github, so I need to hide my SENDGRID_API_KEY in app.yaml.

Part of app.yaml looks like this

```
env_variables:
   SENDGRID_API_KEY: 'my_send_grid_api_key'
```

I already stored all sensitive keys to config.py. so I want to replace 'my_send_grid_api_key' part to cofing.Sendgrid_API_Key or something like this.

How can I import string to app.yaml or points the config.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to store the SendGrid API key as an environment variable?

In your code that makes the call to SendGrid you can just do this:

```
from config import Sendgrid_API_Key
SG = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey= Sendgrid_API_Key)
SG.client.mail.send.post(request_body=data)
```

Comment: The [SendGrid official guide](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) said to set SendGrid API key as an environment variable. I did what you did before and experienced HTTP 401 error and after I simply changed API key to environment variable, The problem has solved.

Comment: That's the way I do it so it can work that way.  There must be something else in your setup causing the 401 errors.

Comment: I don't think SendGrid would know how you set the API key as it's done in your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) module to load the `app.yaml` data into a dict and update it:

```
from config import Sendgrid_API_Key 
import yaml

with open('app.yaml') as f:
    app_data = yaml.load(f)

app_data['env_variables']['SENDGRID_API_KEY'] = Sendgrid_API_Key

with open('app.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(app_data, f)
```

Comment: This solution seems very promising I will try it later and come back Thank you very much.